Problem in android emulator and Ionic 7 live loading
for a few days now I've been experiencing something that stresses me out a lot and I don't know why it's happening. When I run the command:

ionic cap sync android && ionic cap run android -l --external
--host=localhost --disable-host-check --target="Pixel_4_API_31"

There's no way to get the emulator to start properly until you try an indefinite number of times. According to the trace that the command is showing, I see the following error:

[capacitor] Installing
xxxxx\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk... [capacitor]
Starting application activity xxx.app/xxx.MainActivity... [capacitor]
ADBs is unresponsive after 5000ms, killing server and retrying...
[capacitor] Error: Command failed:
xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb -s emulator-5554
shell am start -W -n xxx/xxx.MainActivity [capacitor] adb.exe: device
still authorizing

I have already tried to kill the adb process using adb kill-server and adb-start-server, I have killed the process from the process manager, I have restarted the PC, I have revoked the permissions in the emulator from the developer option and a lot of other things without getting it. solution, has there been an update that broke something?
Thanks.

just use this command: ionic cap sync android && ionic cap run android -l --external Then select device from available list.

I have tried but the same thing happens, the difference between your command and mine is that I add more parameters to avoid having to ask for them interactively...
